# Doctrine ORM findOneBy returning null when given valid ID

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony6

I'm using Doctrine 2.4 on a symfony 6.
I've always used findOneBy without a problem but I'm working on a new project now and for some reason this stopped working and can't understand why.

This does not work as I'm getting null.

```
$test = $this->em->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
```

but

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$test2 = $qb->select('t')
    ->from(MyEntity::class, 't')
    ->where('t.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

This totally works.

I'm trying to understand why the first method is not giving me any results when the value $id is the same and they both use EntityManagerInterface in the constructor.

As i mentioned, I've been using findOneBy for quite some time and never had a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i was focusing so much on the usage that didn't pay attention to my Repository inside the Entity.